# None values populating while merging list to a single column dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I  have  unwanted 'None' values populating while merging list of data into a single column dataframe. I have done NLTK transformations to the orginal data.

**Mycode**

```
def apwords(words):
    filtered_sentence = []
    words = word_tokenize(words)
    for w in words:
        filtered_sentence.append(w)
    return filtered_sentence
addwords = lambda x: apwords(x)
clean = data['Clean_addr'].apply(addwords)


clean =list(clean)
bigram = Phrases(clean, min_count=150, threshold=2)
bigrams = Phraser(bigram)

x=[]
for i in clean:
    x.append(bigrams[i])
y=pd.DataFrame(x)
data['Phrases_Clean_Addr']=y.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.astype(str)), axis=1)
```

**Clean  Data Output**

```
   [['robeco', 'des','voeux', 'rd','central','f','man','yee','building','room','central'],
 ['nikko','asset','management','hk','limi','f','man','yee','building','des','voeux','rd','central'],
 ['cfa','institute','office','f','man','yee','building','des','voeux','rd','central'],
 ['victon','registrations','ltd','room','f','regent','centre','queens','rd','central','central'],
 ['ding','fung','ltd','room','crawford','house','queens','rd','central','central'],
 ['quam','ltd','queens','rd','central','th','th','floors','china','building']
 ['f', 'des', 'voeux', 'rd', 'central'],
 ['f', 'wincome', 'centre', 'des', 'voeux', 'rd', 'central'],
 ['ags', 'f', 'chuangs', 'tower', 'connaught', 'rd', 'central']]
```

**My Current Output**

```
robeco des_voeux rd central f man yee building room central None None None None None None None None None None
nikko asset management hk limi f man yee building des_voeux rd central None None None None None None None None
cfa institute office f man yee building des_voeux rd central None None None None None None None None None None
victon registrations ltd room f regent centre queens_rd central central None None None None None None None None None None
ding fung ltd room crawford house queens_rd central central None None None None None None None None None None None
quam ltd queens_rd central th th floors china building None None None None None None None None None None None
canara bank aon china bldng queens_rd centeal central None None None None None None None None None None None None
gia room f aon china building queens_rd central None None None None None None None None None None None None
zaaba capital ltd_unit b f china building queens_rd central None None None None None None None None None None None
firestar diamond hk nd_floor new henry house ice house rd None None None None None None None None None None
```

**Expected Output**

**All the None values that getting appending to the dataframe should be not there**

```
robeco des_voeux rd central f man yee building room central 
nikko asset management hk limi f man yee building des_voeux rd central 
cfa institute office f man yee building des_voeux rd central 
victon registrations ltd room f regent centre queens_rd central central 
ding fung ltd room crawford house queens_rd central central 
quam ltd queens_rd central th th floors china building
```

Comment: Show us the data...

Comment: @StephenRauch, added to the question

Comment: Please format the data so it can be run.  IE `clean=...`

Comment: @StephenRauch, done updated clean output in the question

Comment: Your data contains syntax errors, and the code has class references that are not defined.  You will get more and better answers if you create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.  Especially make sure that the input and expected data are complete (not pseudo-data), and can be easily cut and and paste into an editor to allow testing proposed solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This is the expected behavior because you created a dataframe from a list of lists of unequal size. In your example, the max length of a list in x is 13. So your dataframe y contains 13 columns. NA values are filled for elements of any row with fewer than 13 entries.

To get the output you are requesting simply add dropna to your apply function.

```
data['Phrases_Clean_Addr']=y.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)
```

---

So the full solution is...

```
x = [['robeco', 'des','voeux', 'rd','central','f','man','yee','building','room','central'],['nikko','asset','management','hk','limi','f','man','yee','building','des','voeux','rd','central'],['cfa','institute','office','f','man','yee','building','des','voeux','rd','central'],['victon','registrations','ltd','room','f','regent','centre','queens','rd','central','central'],['ding','fung','ltd','room','crawford','house','queens','rd','central','central'],['quam','ltd','queens','rd','central','th','th','floors','china','building'],['f', 'des', 'voeux', 'rd', 'central'],['f', 'wincome', 'centre', 'des', 'voeux', 'rd', 'central'],['ags', 'f', 'chuangs', 'tower', 'connaught', 'rd', 'central']]

y = pd.DataFrame(x)

z = y.apply(lambda x: ' '.join(x.dropna().astype(str)), axis=1)

>>> z.values
   array(['robeco des voeux rd central f man yee building room central',
   'nikko asset management hk limi f man yee building des voeux rd central',
   'cfa institute office f man yee building des voeux rd central',
   'victon registrations ltd room f regent centre queens rd central central',
   'ding fung ltd room crawford house queens rd central central',
   'quam ltd queens rd central th th floors china building',
   'f des voeux rd central', 'f wincome centre des voeux rd central',
   'ags f chuangs tower connaught rd central'], dtype=object)
```

Comment: @Rahulrajan see full solution above. Please specify if I misread your post above as this is what I interpreted it to be.